Proof-at-the-end formatting
I am using the proof-at-the-end package and loading the package with
\usepackage[createShortEnv]{proof-at-the-end}
\begin{lemmaE}[Perturbation of semigroup operators]
   Let $A,B \in BL(\XSet)$ % statement continues here...
\end{lemmaE}
\begin{proofE}
  % long proof here, which is displayed at the end 
\end{proofE}

I currently get 
The proof appears at the end of the document, and the text 'See proof on page 27' is automatically generated. I do not like how this text is rendered, as it results in a somewhat dangling sentence, immediately after the Lemma (In all cases, after that sentence one has to open a new paragraph, which looks very weird, as the dangling sentence forms a paragraph on its own.
Reading the package documentation I do not manage to understand how to obtain the behaviour that I want, namely, the proof goes at the end and locally I get
Proof. For the proof see page 27.
or
Proof. See Appendix A.1
Any ideas on this?

You can define your own style for the text of the delayed proof.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[
  createShortEnv,
  conf={my text link},
]{proof-at-the-end}

\pgfkeys{
  /prAtEnd/.cd,
  my text link/.style={
    text link={
      \begin{proof}
      See \hyperref[proof:prAtEnd\pratendcountercurrent]{full proof}
      on page~\pageref{proof:prAtEnd\pratendcountercurrent}
      \end{proof}
    },
  },
}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newcommand{\XSet}{???}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemmaE}[Perturbation of semigroup operators]
   Let $A,B \in BL(\XSet)$ % statement continues here...
\end{lemmaE}
\begin{proofE}
Long proof here, which is displayed at the end 
\end{proofE}

\section{Proofs}

\printProofs

\end{document}


Customize at your leisure.

Thank you @egreg, this is perfect!

As the author of this package I confirm the solution, just in case you want this to be applied by default on all theorems, you can now directly use \pratendSetGlobal{text link=…}, this is a bit quicker to write and does not require you to create a new style.
